# Как вывести текст кнопки на передний план CSS

Tags: html, css, button, hover

Есть код кнопки с анимацией фона по `hover`. Не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы пузыри на фоне не перекрывали текст, `z-index` не помогает.

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/Aner/pen/wvMEZEv)

```css
.wrap {
  background: #893565;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: block;
  max-width: 25vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.bubbles {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ps {
  background: rgba(200, 100, 200, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 65%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 280%;
  transition: 1s ease;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.ps2 {
  background: rgba(200, 100, 200, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 280%;
  transition: 1s linear;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ps3 {
  background: rgba(200, 100, 200, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: -15%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 280%;
  transition: 1s ease;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.wrap:hover .ps {
  transform: translateY(-75%);
}

.wrap:hover .ps2 {
  transform: translateY(-75%);
}

.wrap:hover .ps3 {
  transform: translateY(-75%);
}

#a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#text {
  z-index: 1000
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#" id="a1">
    <div class="bubbles">
      <div class="ps"></div>
      <div class="ps2"></div>
      <div class="ps3"></div>
    </div>
    <span id="text">Link text</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` применяется только к элементам у которых есть какой-нибудь `position`. `z-index 1000` у тега с индексом `text` ничего не делает

Comment: можно ему `position:relative` написать, чтобы ничего не поломалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте позицию отличную от `static`, [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) работает только для позиционированных элементов:

```
#text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000
}
```

Позиция `relative` это наиболее безопасное решение если Вы не хотите что бы элемент выбился из своего естественного flow.

Comment: Благодарю! Не знал про эту особенность z-index

Answer (score 0):

Создайте контейнер relative и внутри него сразу помещайте текст и элементы absolute. Для контейнера задайте z-index: 0, а для элементов absolute задайте z-index: -1

Пример:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  Текст
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-10%);
}
```

Ссылка: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/borderad/pen/zYrJgEz)